# GWR model not working

Tags: r, geographically-weighted-regression

I am trying to build a GWR regression model. The context is a study about air pollution and children+families.

The error is

> new data matrix rows mismatch

I'm not sure what is wrong with my data.

```
# bisquare
print("First, the bi-square function...")
gwr_h_bisquare <- gwr.sel(
  avg_chil + married + common_law + one_parent + medium_income_family + family_size + median_income_lonep
            + age_014 + age_04 + age_59 + age_1014 + age_1519,
  data = no2_pop_join_sp,
  adapt = TRUE,
  gweight = gwr.bisquare)

# Gaussian
print("Next up, the Gaussian function...")
gwr_h_gauss <- gwr.sel(
  MEAN ~ avg_chil + married + common_law + one_parent + medium_income_family + family_size + median_income_lonep
            + age_014 + age_04 + age_59 + age_1014 + age_1519,
  data = no2_pop_join_sp, 
  adapt = TRUE,
  gweight = gwr.Gauss)

#select the Gaussian model
#| label: fit gwr
gwr_fit = gwr(
  MEAN ~ avg_chil + married + common_law,
  data = no2_pop_join_sp,
  adapt = gwr_h_gauss,
  hatmatrix = TRUE,
  se.fit = TRUE)
```

> Error: avg_chil + married + common_law, data = no2_pop_join_sp,  :
> new data matrix rows mismatch

Comment: If something *is* wrong with your data we've not got your data so we can't figure that out. Also, what package are you using for your GWR functions?

Comment: Also your first example call to `gwr` is missing the left-hand side of the formula, so it can't work - I assume its `MEAN~`?

Comment: I've just tried setting up an example data set with all the same names as your data, with random normal data in place, and your code runs for me. So yes, it would seem to be something specific to your data.

Comment: The packages are sp and spgwr

Comment: Its got to be related to your data, since I can run those functions with random data with the same names etc. Do you have missing data? Do you have factors? Do you have 10,000,000 rows? Have you tried working with maybe half the data to see if you get the same error? Or fewer columns?